# What VM should I use?

Tags: machine-learning, tools, cloud-computing

So I am starting a project that has some code in it that has to do with machine learning (for example recommender system).
At the moment I am thinking that if I want to deploy this application, should I look into the VM´s that are dedicated to Machine Learning applications or can a regular VM run these kinds of operations as well? What are the differences between them?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Honestly, just use docker; everything else is just inferior.